# Компиляция OPUS кодека c ресурсов под Asterisk 13.18 на базе OpenWRT

Tags: компиляция, asterisk, openwrt, libopus

На данный момент OpenWRT установлен на роутер [TP-Link TL-WR1043ND v4.x](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/tp-link/tp-link_tl-wr1043nd_v4) на базе `Qualcomm Atheros QCA9563`. Нужно скомпилировать `codec_opus.so` по него как это сделать? Спасибо

Comment: Опенврт какой версии?

Comment: @eri Сейчас имею  `OpenWRT 4.9.75`

Comment: Это из 90ых что-то? 15 версия актуальна.

Comment: @eri Епс... да вы правы в данному случае это версия ядра линукс. Отновительно сборки у меня `dev` версия `OpenWrt SNAPSHOT r5740-012d20e / LuCI Master (git-18.009.50819-7749af8)` Спасибо за замечания

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вообще кодеки на роутере?

Comment: @eri в данном случае астериск использует отдельные модули с [репозитория](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/packages/mips_24kc/telephony/) OpenWrt  но к сожалению некоторы кодеки просто отсутвуют в частности `opus`

Comment: Дело в сборочной СДК. В 12ой то жесть была, в 15ой все просто делается. Надо только написать мэйкфайл. На работе набросаю пример

Comment: @eri спасибо тебе за помощь. Существуют какие то гайды как можно создать среду для сбоки на маке или даже на виртуалке для на линуск?

Comment: @eri подкинешь какой-то мануальчик по компиляции? Спасибо